# application of the mean value theorem for a function of $C^{1}$ class.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ of class $C^{1}$ in the open and convex set $U\subset R^{m}$, with $0\in U$ and $f(0)=0$. If $|f'(x)|\leq |x|$ for all $x\in U $, then $|f(x)|\leq\frac{1}{2}|x|^{2}$ for all $x\in U$.

Comment: I tried to use the fact that if $U$ is a convex set and $0\in U$, then for all $x\in U$, $\left\[ 0,x \right\]\subseteq U$, and $\left\[ 0,x \right\]$ is a compact set in $U$. Therefore, $f$ is uniformly differentiable since $f$ is $C^{1}$. I do not know if I can choose a suitable $\epsilon$ to be able to limit the value of f in x such that the desired inequality is given

Comment: I think you can prove that $|f(x)| \leq |x|^2 / 2$.

Comment: yes, I didn't write the square of the norm of x, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in U$ and $g(t) = f(tx)$. Then
$$f(x) = f(x)-f(0) = g(1)-g(0) = \int_0^1 g^{\prime}(t)\, dt = \int_0^1 x\cdot f^{\prime}(tx)\, dt \le \int_0^1 t|x|^2\, dt = |x|^2/2.$$
I am quite sure that's what you really want.

Comment: Thanks, I miss writing the square of $|x|$ in the last inequality. You are very kind, it helps me a lot.